# Select elements within <div> and <iframe>

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

We started test automation on our web app (ASP.NET). We should've done it ages ago and the meantime the app has become complex so our Selenium progress is very slow.
I'm completely new to Selenium and I have a situation, well, right from the start. Our app, upon clicking a button on the main form opens a dialog.

This how it looks like in the inspect element:

```html
<div id="ModalPopupControl_PW-1" class="dxpcLite dxpclW dxpc-mainDiv dxpc-shadow" style="width: 975px; cursor: default; z-index: 12000; visibility: visible; display: table; position: absolute; height: 713px; left: 132px; top: 66px;">
  <div class="dxpc-header dxpc-withBtn" style="cursor:move;-khtml-user-select:none;" id="ModalPopupControl_PWH-1">
    <div class="dxpc-closeBtn" id="ModalPopupControl_HCB-1">
      <img class="dxWeb_pcCloseButton" src="/Client/DXR.axd?r=1_37-WyBvg" alt="[Close]">
    </div>
    <div class="dxpc-headerContent" style="padding-left: 0px !important; padding-right: 18px !important; line-height: 10px; height: 14px;">
      <span class="dxpc-headerText dx-vam" id="ModalPopupControl_PWH-1T"></span>
    </div>
    <b class="dx-clear">
    </b>
  </div>
  <div class="dxpc-contentWrapper" style="display: table; height: 692px;">
    <div class="dxpc-content" style="padding: 0px; display: block; height: 692px;" id="ModalPopupControl_PWC-1">
      <iframe id="ModalPopupControl_CIF-1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" src="Controls/NewDoc/NewDocumentPage.aspx" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; backface-visibility: hidden; vertical-align: text-bottom;">  </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, it's div, with an iframe in it.

I can select the dialog using an CssSelector, but no matter what the element WITHIN new pop-up dialog - I can't reach it using selenium.

My attempt to get it is pretty straightforward:

```c#
Driver.chrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#newDocumentControl_CallbackPanelShowGrids_rbSelection_RB1_I_D")).Click();
```

Error I get is:

```
{"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"css selector\",\"selector\":\"#newDocumentControl_btnCancel\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)"}
```

I've tried `SwitchTo().Alert`, MoveTo element, searching by z index...

I'm using Chrome, Visual Studio 2017 and C#.

I could really, really use some tips...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DOM this element is not present

`newDocumentControl_CallbackPanelShowGrids_rbSelection_RB1_I_D`

can you please show the element exactly you want to select

does you want to select `<iframe>` ?

and if you want to select `iframe`

do as this

```c#
Driver.chrome.FindElement(By.id("ModalPopupControl_CIF-1")).Click();
```

or this

```c#
 WebElement iframeSwitch = driver.findElement(By.id("ModalPopupControl_CIF-1"));
 driver.switchTo().frame(iframeSwitch);
```

Comment: I don't believe this! It works! Oh, one more thing...when I'm done, I'll close the <iframe> on X or Cancel button. Will Selenium know that I'm back in the main window or should I somehow manually switch it back like you did on the <iframe>?

Comment: Wait...URL is always the same. It's a dialog windows that I'm switching to. It has no URL. Once I'm done, I need to switch back to the main window....

Comment: @NikolaPepic sorry ! your right

Comment: But I'm not sure how to approach this. In your example, you grabbed the ID of the dialog, then swithed to it. When I close it, it seems that Selenium still has it in focus and I can't grab elements in main to switch to it...because it is not in focus. How could I get around this?

Comment: try this out `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`